# Is there a way to password-protect part of a post?

Tags: conditional-content, password

Is there a way to have a page displayed to the public, but have an extra custom field that doesn't display unless a password is entered?

I suppose I could do entirely manually without WordPress functions at all but I'd like to know if there was a WordPress solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it the other way around: Put the always visible text into a [custom field per metabox](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77323/73), and protect the post content with a password.

In your theme, always show the custom field, and let WordPress handle the password protection.

Sample code for the theme:

```
while ( have_posts() )
{
    the_post();

    if ( post_password_required( $post ) )
    {
        print '<h1 class="post-protect-notice">' .
            __( 'Protected Post', 't5_theme' )
            . '</h1>';
        the_excerpt();
        // custom field
        print wpautop(
            get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_always_visible_content', TRUE )
        );
    }
    else
    {
        // show regular content
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Toscho, gonna look into that, but how to show the content with password on the same page? Or should I make 2 seperate pages, one password protected and one not

Comment: @LuckyLuke See my update with a code sample.

Comment: Thats good, but what determines if post_password_required? None of my users are logged in, but I want to give out a password manually to my friends to see this private content (like a price).

Comment: `post_password_required()` is `TRUE` if you set a post password. You could also let your friends create subscriber accounts and show the extra content only when `is_user_logged_in()` is `TRUE`.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought about checking if they are logged in. But for your first option, let me see if I get you. I set a post password, but even on restricted pages I show all the info from the custom fields except the main content (which contains the price). If they enter password then all is shown. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: Great, I appreciate your time and effort!