# Display page content in different sections - based on page break block?

Tags: php, loop, pages

Is there a way to loop through page content, and display the content that is above page break in one section, and everything that is below the page break in another? Or additionally, a way to generate sections based on multiple page breaks? I need to build a landing page, that shows a starting part of page in a certain way, and all other content in different one. 
I tried to find the solution but most of the articles are about breaking posts in to more than one page. What I need is a solution for page, not post and one that uses page break to split content to sections, not pages.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106570/how-to-grab-a-specific-page-of-content-from-paginated-post): It partially resolves my problem but breaks the gutenberg blocks, rendering some of them unusable. I would greatly appriciate help with this...